# adding image from html page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to add picture or files to my database to maximum 5 people. in html page user selects their files and people who want to share and submits. But I stuck in files part. it keeps me giving errors.

here is my database codes:

```
Create Database webpage;
use webpage
Create table user(Firstname varchar(40) NOT NULL,Lastname Varchar(40) NOT NULL,username varchar(20) NOT NULL,password varchar(16) NOT NULL,address varchar (70),university varchar (75),approval INT,PRIMARY KEY (username));
Create Table datas(Username varchar(20),imagesnotes LONGBLOB NOT NULL,Foreign Key (Username) References user(username));
Create Table Administrator(Firstname varchar(40) NOT NULL,Lastname Varchar(40) NOT NULL,username varchar (20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,password varchar (16) NOT NULL);
Create Table userdata(username varchar(20) NOT NULL,imagesnotes LONGBLOB NOT NULL,sharedpeople varchar (100) NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE userdata
ADD FOREIGN KEY (sharedpeople)
References user(username);
```

Here is my php page which user will select their files and people who want to share:
upload.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$username =$_SESSION["uname"];
?>
<h3>Hello again, <?php echo $username; ?>. From here, you can upload your photos or texts for only 5 people. So make your decisions carefully.</h3>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>

<form action="uploaded.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image or text to upload:
    <input type="file" name="image" value='Select folder to upload'>

  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  People You Want To Choose:
  <br>
  <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webpage");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM user");

echo "Username 1";

echo'<select name="username1">';
echo'<option value="" selected="selected">Select a Username</option>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

{
    echo'<option value="' . $row['username'] . '">'. $row['username'] .'</option>';
}
echo'</select></p><p>';

mysqli_close($con);
?>       

 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webpage");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM user");

echo "Username 2";

echo'<select name="username2">';
echo'<option value="" selected="selected">Select a Username</option>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

{
    echo'<option value="' . $row['username'] . '">'. $row['username'] .'</option>';
}
echo'</select></p><p>';

mysqli_close($con);
?>       

 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webpage");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM user");

echo "Username 3";

echo'<select name="username3">';
echo'<option value="" selected="selected">Select a Username</option>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

{
    echo'<option value="' . $row['username'] . '">'. $row['username'] .'</option>';
}
echo'</select></p><p>';

mysqli_close($con);
?>      

 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webpage");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM user");

echo "Username 4";

echo'<select name="username4">';
echo'<option value="" selected="selected">Select a Username</option>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

{
    echo'<option value="' . $row['username'] . '">'. $row['username'] .'</option>';
}
echo'</select></p><p>';

mysqli_close($con);
?>       

 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webpage");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM user");

echo "Username 5";

echo'<select name="username5">';
echo'<option value="" selected="selected">Select a Username</option>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

{
    echo'<option value="' . $row['username'] . '">'. $row['username'] .'</option>';
}
echo'</select></p><p>';

echo'<input type="submit" value="Submit" />';


mysqli_close($con);
?>        
</br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my php to confirm the operations:
uploaded.php

I didn't put the sql queries for now. First I want to do that if the all parts are null, it must bring me error that there is no file or person to share.But I keep getting these error:

"Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\Project2\members\uploaded.php on line 15"
What should I suppose to do?

Thanks.

Update:
I have problems with functions. I want to do that if something comes from sql query make another query if it doesn't bring anything show the message but I get nothing:
uploaded.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$username =$_SESSION["uname"];
?>
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "webpage");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$username1 = $_POST["username1"];
$username2 = $_POST["username2"];
$username3 = $_POST["username3"];
$username4 = $_POST["username4"];
$username5 = $_POST["username5"];
$image = $_FILES["image"];

$sql = "select username from user where username = '$username1'";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_NUM);

while($row==1){

$sql2 = mysqli_query($con,"insert into userdata values '$username','$image','$username1'");
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 file added";
}if(empty($sql)){
 echo "you didn't select anybody or a file";
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: First off, dont stack br tags, it's not a good way to do it, It's better to wrap the content in a div and then use margin/padding with css. The undefined index is probably because you have to put the `$image = "";` at the top of the page for variable declaration. You can put it beneath `$username =$_SESSION["uname"];` I would recommend you to use an else statement after your if statement to be on the safe side, it might be executed when you dont want it to otherwise.

Comment: FYI: its not going into `$_POST['image']`. Its in `$_FILES['image']`

Comment: I made $_POST['image'] to $_FILES['image'] but it gets me same error.

Comment: @JimSundqvist I tried what you said and made $_POST['image'] to $_FILES['image'] but it still don't work.

Comment: @Ghost i believe his comment was for you

Comment: @Ghost it was also for you too I forgot to mention your name sorry.

Comment: @Ghost i believe his comment was for you

Comment: @JimSundqvist oh i was watching a movie lol thanks for the ping. anyways, just debug variables like you would normally do `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_FILES)` on form submission, you'll see the indices which you will need for your insertion

Comment: @Ghost sorry but I didn't understand what you're saying :D

Comment: @Ghost I edited my problem can you look at it please?